# What is the easiest way to add Google Font to a React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running in to trouble trying to add Google Fonts in to my React Application, Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import it like this

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
</style>
```

Within the `<head>` tag in your index.html file

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it available across your whole application, you can simply include a stylesheet tag in your index.html

[image: Google fonts screenshot]

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then you can simply style your component

```
const Komponent = () => (
  <h1 style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto' }}> Styled Text </h1>
);
```